# What's "flag weight"?

Tags: support

On my profile page it shows a number after "flag weight". I understand it's related to the number of flagged questions/answers, but what exactly does the number signify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It represents how useful your close/reopen/moderator etc flaggings have been.

Every time you flag something and the action you flagged it for gets taken your flag weight increases.  If the flag is 'declined' then your flag weight decreases.

People with larger flag weights get their flags higher up the lists on the moderator pages so they are more likely to be acted on faster.

There is a formula somewhere that defines how much your flag weight increases with each correct flagging.  After a flag weight of 500 you start getting less and less weight per flag.

The official FAQ entry is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight

Comment: It does not represent "Right" in all reality. It is a method for mods to give feedback on flags so that users that give good flags have their flags at the top of their list. You stated all that for the most part, but I do not want someone whom got a flag labeled invalid to feel they were wrong, they may be 100% correct, it just did not help the moderators solve problems.

Comment: "right" removed.  Better?

Comment: Thanks, that FAQ was what I was looking for. At the moment my flag weight still shows integers. Not sure what it will be when the actual value has a fraction. Anyway, information-wise a displayed number of "517" is exactly the same as "517.0891", so I don't need the decimals displayed.

Comment: @Matt, no need to remove it, it really was not "wrong" either, just some clarity for someone to not feel when they see invalid that it does mean they were wrong.

Comment: @kortuk It's too late now... it's gone... There's no getting it back again ;)